# SQL: How to display the percentage of passed and failed students?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has the data of students and their results.

```
ID  Name  Result
1   St1   FAIL
2   St2   PASS
3   St3   PASS
4   St4   PASS
5   St5   FAIL
6   St6   PASS
```

I want the total percentage of passed and failed students rounded off to 2 decimal places. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(
        SUM(
            CONVERT(
                FLOAT,
                CASE WHEN Result = 'PASS' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                     END
            )
        )
        /COUNT(*) * 100,
        2
    ) AS 'Pass',
    ROUND(
        SUM(
            CONVERT(
                FLOAT,
                CASE WHEN Result = 'FAIL' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                     END
            )
        )
        /COUNT(*) * 100,
        2
    ) AS 'Fail' 
FROM StudentsResults
```

Result:

```
Pass    Fail
66.67   33.33
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another option without a count()

**Example**

```
Select Pass = round(avg(case when Result='Pass' then 100.0 else 0.0 end),2)
      ,Fail = round(avg(case when Result='Fail' then 100.0 else 0.0 end),2)
 From  YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Pass    Fail
66.67   33.33
```

Answer (score 1):

How about with a group by clause?

```
select round(cast(count(Name) as decimal)/cast((select count(*) from StudentPassFail) as decimal)*100,2), result from StudentPassFail 
group by result;
```

Comment: I'm not getting desired output for this. I'm getting both values as 0

Comment: Show me the sql you executed

Comment: Here it is.
 select round(count(Name)/(select count(*)from StudentPassFail)*100 ,2), result from StudentPassFail group by result;

Comment: Sry, forgot the casts as decimal. Corrected in the answer